# __autoload mix up?

Tags: php, autoload, spl

I have a server with many customers on, when I develop I include my init.php in which I have an `__autoloader()` function that includes the file with `dir_name(__FILE__)."/classes/".$className` for instance.

But yesterday I saw that the server could not find the specific class, I restartat apache and then it worked again.

Every customer has this own init.php...  ( and therefore many __autoloads on the same server )

```
customer1/init.php            : holds __autoload()
customer1/classes/class.php

customer2/init.php            : holds __autoload()
customer2/classes/class.php
```

I have not done some tests and I hope someone can answer my question before I try to reproduce the problem, but do you think it is possible for php to take the wrong autoload function when you get 2 or more requests at the same time?

Is spl_autoload_register the solution?

Many thanks for some ideas or brainstorming.

Comment: you have a typo idéas => ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you should have a typo in either one of your __autoload() functions or you are including the wrong init.php file.

Also, dir_name() does not exist, you should change that to [dirname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)() instead or you can also use the new [**DIR** constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) for the same effect if you're using PHP >= 5.3.

**EDIT:** In light of your comment, use should use:

```
require(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/classes/' . $className);
```

or

```
require(realpath(__DIR__) . '/classes/' . $className);
```

Comment: I never use the absolute path when including the init.php... include (dirname(__FILE__).'/../init.php');

Comment: Indeed, I don't know how that skipped my eyes. chdir() or similar should be messing with your code, using the above code should solve your problem.

Comment: Cool,  I will try to reproduce my problem tonight, and they try your solution.  Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

Each PHP request is completely separate, in fact it is impossible for you to have two functions named `__autoload()` in the same PHP request, so they cannot interfere. Possible problems:

- You are including the wrong customer's `init.php`
- You forgot to include the `init.php` file, in which case there is *no* autoloading at all.

Comment: Yeah, but it have worked for about 3 months. Saw it the first time yesterday but I had a similar problem before when I had this structure

/test/classes/class.php
/test/init.php
/classes/class.php
/init.php

So /test/ is a copy of /...   When I navigated to /test sometimes I got the same problem with the autoload....  Restarted the server and then it worked for some time until I started surfing on the / and so on...